# Need help in constructing Microsoft Graph API url

Tags: sharepointdocumentlibrary, microsoft-graph-files

I am trying to access files from DocumentLibrarie (DL) available in SharePoint online using Graph API.  As per Microsoft's Graph API documentation this needs to be done using {driveId}.  To fetch the **driveId** i am using user-friendly DL name, as shown below:

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/{hostname}:/sites/{document library name}:/drives
```

and to access individual document sets, i will use the {driveId} that is obtained from the previous REST call.  The url to fetch files from individual document sets is as below,

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/drives/{driveId}/root:/{documentSetName}:/children
```

The driveId is not in user-readable form (its about 66 chars in length).  I was wondering if it is feasible to achieve this using url below (or, something similar), essentially to use the document library name to access the files in Graph.

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/{hostname}:/sites/{document library name}:/drives/{documentSetName}:/children
```

Please let me if this is feasible.  Also, do you see such an option has its utility.